# VBA in Excel returning Type mismatch

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to create a Macro that will modify contents in columns S, W and AH based on the content in AB
e.g. if AB1 = No, then S1=C-MEM, AH = N/A and W is cleared.

For some reason, I get a 'Type mismatch' error on the first line of my if statement and can't figure out why or how to fix it - even after reading other posts about similar issue.

```
Sub test()
    Dim lastrow As Long
    Dim i As Long
    lastrow = Range("AB" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    For i = 2 To lastrow
    **->  If Range("AB" & i).Value = "No" Then
            Range("S" & i).Value = "C-MEM"
            Range("W" & i).Value = ""
            Range("AH" & i).Value = "N/A"
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

Thanks

Comment: Hm, I can't duplicate your error. It works okay for me. (Excel 2016).  Create a brand new workbook, throw some data in column `AB` and see if it works then.

Comment: You probably have errors in the column.

Comment: I've had this macro work once or twice too. I think part of the problem is I have other macros running prior to that one for the same columns. I suspect the other macros might be somehow changing the property of the columns/cells? The odd thing is when I try this macro on another column of the same sheet, it works fine.

Comment: This macro is not. The one running prior are.

Comment: When you step though, is `lastRow` > 2?

Comment: What is the value in cell `"AB & i` when this errors out?

Comment: @port yeah and that wouldn't give a mismatch error anyway.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are trying to test if an error is = `No`.

Test for the error and skip the logic in that loop:

```
Sub test()
    Dim lastrow As Long
    Dim i As Long
    lastrow = Range("AB" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    For i = 2 To lastrow
        If Not IsError(Range("AB" & i).Value) Then
            If Range("AB" & i).Value = "No" Then
                Range("S" & i).Value = "C-MEM"
                Range("W" & i).Value = ""
                Range("AH" & i).Value = "N/A"
            End If
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: You're saying that *ABi* could be a formula resulting in an error, right?

Comment: @Raystafarian that was the intent of my assumption.